# Using ILSpy, how do I navigate to the Resource string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ilspy

I'm browsing through the `System.Web.Mvc` library and I don't know how to navigate to the resource files.

I see a line of code like this...

```cs
throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "contentPath");
```

So I click through on `Common_NullOrEmpty`, which brings here

```cs
// System.Web.Mvc.Resources.MvcResources
internal static string Common_NullOrEmpty
{
    get
    {
        return MvcResources.ResourceManager.GetString("Common_NullOrEmpty", MvcResources.resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for `Common_NullOrEmpty` with no results.

Where are these resources buried?  and more importantly, how would I go about finding this on my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the resources under the Assembly in the Tree View:

[image: Resources]

You are then shown a table on the right with all the strings in:

[image: Resource Strings]

Sometimes I have to click "Save" at the top of the Resource View and look at them in NotePad++ if I cannot find them in that list.

Comment: Wow, you answered so fast I can't "accept as an answer" for another 6 minutes.  Another feature hidden in plain sight.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I hope they add a search feature to the Resource Strings, then it would be perfect.

Comment: @Dave, hi as Microsoft has opened source the MVC framework now, I have a question, how could I access the MvcResources class from inside my own custom html helper method? Thank you!